# New Ruby app with postgresql gets active-record sqlite3 errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, sqlite, rails-activerecord

I started a new app with `rails new myapp --database=postgresql`
I can't even start developing because this happens. This is my console:

```
$ rails generate controller home
Warning: Running `gem pristine --all` to regenerate your installed gemspecs (and deleting then reinstalling your bundle if you use bundle --path) will improve the startup performance of Spring.
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/connection_specification.rb:177:in `rescue in spec': Specified 'sqlite3' for database adapter, but the gem is not loaded. Add `gem 'sqlite3'` to your Gemfile (and ensure its version is at the minimum required by ActiveRecord). (Gem::LoadError)
```

However this is my Gem file:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'


# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.2.1'
# Use postgresql as the database for Active Record
gem 'pg'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# Use CoffeeScript for .coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.1.0'
# See https://github.com/rails/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'
# Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/rails/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
# bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0', group: :doc

# Twitter bootstrap
gem 'twitter-bootstrap-rails', '~> 3.2.0'
# Devise for user authentication
gem 'devise', '~> 3.4.1'
# GitHub OAuth2
gem 'omniauth-github', '~> 1.1.2'
# Facebook OAuth2
gem 'omniauth-facebook'
# Dribbble OAuth
gem 'omniauth-dribbble', '~> 0.0.1'
# LinkedIn OAuth2
gem "linkedin-oauth2", "~> 1.0"
# To enable features such as static asset serving and logging on Heroku
gem 'rails_12factor', group: :production

# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use Unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug'

  # Access an IRB console on exception pages or by using <%= console %> in views
  gem 'web-console', '~> 2.0'

  # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
  gem 'spring'
end
```

This is my database.yml:

```
# PostgreSQL. Versions 8.2 and up are supported.
#
# Install the pg driver:
#   gem install pg
# On OS X with Homebrew:
#   gem install pg -- --with-pg-config=/usr/local/bin/pg_config
# On OS X with MacPorts:
#   gem install pg -- --with-pg-config=/opt/local/lib/postgresql84/bin/pg_config
# On Windows:
#   gem install pg
#       Choose the win32 build.
#       Install PostgreSQL and put its /bin directory on your path.
#
# Configure Using Gemfile
# gem 'pg'
#
default: &default
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  # For details on connection pooling, see rails configuration guide
  # http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#database-pooling
  pool: 5

development:
  <<: *default
  database: myapp_development
  username: myapp
  password: PASSWORD
  host: localhost
  port: 5432


  # Schema search path. The server defaults to $user,public
  #schema_search_path: myapp,sharedapp,public

  # Minimum log levels, in increasing order:
  #   debug5, debug4, debug3, debug2, debug1,
  #   log, notice, warning, error, fatal, and panic
  # Defaults to warning.
  #min_messages: notice

# Warning: The database defined as "test" will be erased and
# re-generated from your development database when you run "rake".
# Do not set this db to the same as development or production.
test:
  <<: *default
  database: myapp_test

# As with config/secrets.yml, you never want to store sensitive information,
# like your database password, in your source code. If your source code is
# ever seen by anyone, they now have access to your database.
#
# Instead, provide the password as a unix environment variable when you boot
# the app. Read http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#configuring-a-database
# for a full rundown on how to provide these environment variables in a
# production deployment.
#
# On Heroku and other platform providers, you may have a full connection URL
# available as an environment variable. For example:
#
#   DATABASE_URL="postgres://myuser:mypass@localhost/somedatabase"
#
# You can use this database configuration with:
#
#   production:
#     url: <%= ENV['DATABASE_URL'] %>
#
production:
  <<: *default
  database: myapp_production
  username: myapp
  password: <%= ENV['MYAPP_DATABASE_PASSWORD'] %>
```

My Gemfile.lock is also free of any sqlite3 and I haven't been able to find a solution to this for the past 2 days even after starting from scratch a couple of times.

Comment: Are you certain `$DATABASE_URL` is not set?  `printenv | grep DATABASE_URL` for instance should return nothing.  For more information, see Section 3.14 of Configuration Rails Applications http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#configuring-a-database.

Comment: @steveklein yes it's not set and `printenv | grep DATABASE_URL` returns nothing and when running `bin/rails runner 'puts ActiveRecord::Base.configurations'{"development"=>{"adapter"=>"postgresql", "host"=>"localhost", "database"=>"myapp_development", "pool"=>5}}` I get the same activerecord error as with `rails generate controller home`